# How to fork jvm when Play framework triggers a re-load

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.4

What I am trying to do is to fork the JVM process whenever Play framework does a re-load after sbt detects that I have made a change in my source code. Is there a way for me to spawn a new jvm and kill the original process?

What I have tried is adding the following to my build.sbt file:

```
fork in run := true
```

Then I run 'sbt' in command line, then 'run', but I don't see any new jvm's spawning in my processes.

Comment: Please tell us what you have already tried. Like "fork in run := true" and did not work. That will help to find the correct answer :)

Comment: @JonasAnso I have edited my post with what I have tried.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. I can't run the Play applicaiton with different Java memory options than those used to run SBT itself as a result. Did you find a solution to this?